# Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to run the following selenium python code and trying to find the element by xpath. It's running down with error unable to locate element. Below is the code which I'm trying to run

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='850']/input").click
```

**HTML Code is**

```
<input class="analysts ui-autocomplete-input"
    style="width:90%;" onfocus="getTeamWiseAnalyst('TM');"
    onkeypress="
        if(event.keyCode == 13) {
            changeValue(this,analysts_map);
            saveAssignee('TM',697511, 2,false);
        }"
    value="madhura.pandit"
    autocomplete="off"
    type="text"
/>
```

Please let me know what should I do. How I can find the web element. Is there any method to find this web element.

Comment: You need to provide more html, the minimum is the html you are using to locate the element (`id='850'` in your case).

Comment: Made code possible to read.

Comment: not familiar with Python, but try locate the element by class.
Use "find_elements" and use the click on the element according to the index. if you have just one class as described then the first element etc...
as Guy said, we can't see the Id you described in the HTML you shared with us.